# can't access fortrabbit mysql db through terminal (ssh)

Tags: mysql, ssh, laravel, fortrabbit

I can't access mysql through terminal on fortrabbit. I follow all steps but it is rejecting my password. However I can regullary login through ssh and edit my application. Anyone had that issue ? Thanks.

Comment: fortrabbit doesnt allow remote connections.  If you download sequel pro, you can use an ssh connection then connect to the database through localhost

Comment: From fortrabbit:
So you need to access the MySQL database on fortrabbit remotely. For this you can either install a web MySQL administration tool (Chive or phpMyAdmin) on the remote server or you can open a tunnel using SSH and then connect to the database via the tunnel.

Comment: yeah... do you have sequel pro installed on your computer?  It's free software and is great for this

Comment: I am using Linux/Ubuntu. They also offer sequel pro alternative (Chive web GUI) but this doesn't work also.Maybe fortrabbit temporary bug.

Comment: Isn't this a question for Fortrabbit support?

Comment: Of course, but they have a link to SO for questions. → ask question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this in the past using a [SSH tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol).  You open an SSH tunnel to the server, and then you connect to the MySQL server there from the endpoint of that tunnel.  As such, to MySQL you appear to be connecting locally.

**From the terminal:**

First you need to open the tunnel, you can do it like this:

```
ssh -N -L8889:127.0.0.1:3306 username@your.fortrabbit.domain.com &
```

This opens port 8889, then opens a tunnel to `your.fortrabbit.domain.com`, then forwards that local port *through* the tunnel to the IP 127.0.0.1 and port 3306 *relative* to the server at `your.fortrabbit.domain.com`.

The options in more detail:

**`-N`**: Do not execute a remote command.
**`-L`**: Specifies the ports (local and remote).
**`8889`**: Your local port that is being forwarded.
**`127.0.0.1`**: the remote IP to which you're forwarding, relative to the server which ssh is connecting to
**`3306`**: the remote port to which you're forwarding.
**`username@your.fortrabbit.domain.com`**: Your username and domain with fortrabbit.

Now you're ready to open the connection.  In the same terminal, use the following command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 8889 -u mysql-username -p
```

port 8889 is now being forwarded to the port and IP of your MySQL server on the fortrabbit side, so just replace `mysql-username` with your username on the mysql server, and you're connected!

**From a GUI:**

You mentioned in your comments that you're using Ubuntu, so install MySQL Workbench from the Software Centre or [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/), create a `New Connection` and select the connection type as "`Standard TCP/IP over SSH`".

You will need to configure the following:

**`SSH Hostname`**: the hostname or IP of your ssh account with fortrabbit
**`SSH Username`**: your username with them
**`SSH Password`**: your password with them
**`SSH Keyfile`**:  If you use keys for authentication, select the private one here.
**`MySQL Hostname`**: 127.0.0.1 (because it's local to the endpoint of your tunnel.
**`MySQL Server Port`**: normally "3306".
**`Username`**: The username for the DB
**`Password`**: The password for the DB
**`Default Schema`**: Whatever should be the default schema for this DB (can be left blank).

That should then connect from wherever you are!

Comment: OK I managed to login with chive -it is a free web gui - very similar to sequel pro. But still I miss terminal entry. I tried your solutions but it doesnt work. Maybe some problems with ssh keys ?

Comment: strange - it should Just Work if you can SSH to the server normally.. do you use a key normally?  or a password?

Comment: Yes it is working now. I got reply from frbit stuff. I didn't enter my app name properly. I am a big fun of terminal but opening two terminals just to access db remotely is too much. Any way thanks for response.

Comment: just put an & on the end of the command, and it will put the SSH session into the background, allowing you to do it from one terminal.. I'll update the amswer