# Laravel 5.1 Fortrabbit Mysql SSH 'tunnel' not working

Tags: mysql, ssh, laravel-5.1, fortrabbit

I tired to use 'tunnel' comments in Fortrabbit's website to migate my database, but it doesn't work. http://help.fortrabbit.com/mysql#toc-remote-mysql-access

I can deploy my website and everything's fine except I need to migrate my database.Since I can see my webpages up there I assume my public/private SSH keys are set correctly.

I'm using exactly like here:
[can't access fortrabbit mysql db through terminal (ssh)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026681/cant-access-fortrabbit-mysql-db-through-terminal-ssh) answer by msturdy but hasn't been lucky.

I opened the bash and used:

```
ssh -N -L 33060:xxxxxx.mysql.eu2.frbit.com:3306 tunnel@tunnel.eu2.frbit.com
```

but the screen just freezes and nothing happens.

I have worked on this error for several hours now, tried everything but couldn't resolve it, please help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour, see the docs:

http://help.fortrabbit.com/mysql#toc-terminal-tunnel-mysql

```
# open the tunnel on local port 13306
$ ssh -N -L 13306:my-app.mysql.eu2.frbit.com:3306 tunnel@tunnel.eu2.frbit.com
```

> **This command will not reply with any message on success!** If nothing shows up: you did right! This behavior is how most (all?) SSH
>   clients are implemented and sadly we cannot issue any response message
>   telling you that it worked. So mind: If you see no error, all is good.